# Is this post appropriate for the main site?

Tags: discussion

I'm a high school student from India, I got a question regarding SAT Subject Tests but I'm not sure if I can post it on the main site. Is there some other site where I can get help? My post is below:

---

**NOTE:** *I do not have any intentions to offend anyone. I'm in no way trying to insult the US education system so if at any point my post suggest that I'm, I apologize.*

I have a SAT Maths II and Physics Subject Test this Saturday(4 Nov), I just bought Barron's Books to preparation and to my surprise, the test felt way to easy. It's like too good to be true so my question is; is it really that easy or I'm being trolled by the book?

**Talking about Physics**
I checked a full length paper on cracksat.com too. The questions are mostly conceptual which is nice cause calculator is not allowed but even then they are really easy. Time is surely a problem, I mean 75 ques in 60 mins, is mad.

But are SAT Subject Tests made this easy?
[Take a Look at this for example](http://www.cracksat.net/sat2/physics/test616.html)

---

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Massimo's answer, questions pertaining to high school students that are not research-oriented are automatically considered off-topic.

Comment: Okay but could you at least recommend where I can get some help? It’s imp. for me

Comment: Sorry—I'm not sure what kind of forums out there handle such questions. I'm sure they're out there, though, and you could probably search for them.

Answer (score 2):

As is, your question would be quite probably considered off topic, because we don't assess the quality of tests, books etc.

A general question about the difficulty of standardized tests could be potentially interesting, but it would be too broad or too much opinion based.

For what it's worth, I find the linked questions from the test rather depressing.